# People says machine understands binary code, that is 0 and 1 is that literally true?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, binary

What i meant to say that 0 and 1 is still a perceptive number that human to understand so how come machine understands this? If machine can get 0 and 1 it can equally understand alphabets also. So where i am missing the concept?

Comment: There's no understanding in the human sense, it's a figure of speech.

Comment: Machines understand nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Machines don't actually understand a 1 or a 0 as a number the way we do. What we mean by 1 or 0 (in the context of machine language) is really just a high or a low voltage value stored in some sort of charge storage structure (often a MOS capacitor these days).

Answer (score 4):

On a very low level, microcontrollers/microprocessors are made of numerous transistors acting as switches.  You can think of each transistor as only having two states: "on" and "off".

These transistors are driven by voltages.  If we apply a voltage, we get a specific behavior.  If we remove the voltage, we get the other behavior.

We need a convenient way to say whether a transistor has a voltage applied or not.  It is customary to say "1" if there is an applied voltage, or "0" if there is none.

So, computers don't actually understand "zeros and ones", as we think of them.  They operate based on where the voltages are applied.  But since we refer to these voltage states as "zeros and ones", the language usage makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

"0" and "1" are essentially concepts, ideas that we can use to represent the absence or presence of something. The computer cannot understand "0" or "1" however it - or even a lamp bulb - can "understand" the presence or absence of voltage. There is no real understanding here : the lamp merely glows in the presence of voltage, and goes dark in its absence.

The computer can do slightly more : but even so, it can only turn on or off switches, affecting the presence or absence of voltage somewhere else.

For example, a small component in it can turn a switch on when two separate wires (we'll call them "A" and "B") both have voltage present. Then we can write a "truth table" for its operation:

A   B   switch
0   0   0
1   0   0
0   1   0
1   1   1

Now you can see that this table represents the sentence above : the switch is only ON (1) when voltage is present (1) on both **A and B**. Otherwise the switch is off.

So we call this component an "AND gate".

Two similar components are the NOT gate (a switch which is OFF when its input is ON and vice versa, and the OR gate, which switches on when either A or B or both are ON.

What makes binary code so powerful is that these three elements, AND OR and NOT, can be combined  (in sufficient numbers) to perform all of mathematics, encode textual alphabets (this message), photos, music, speech. That's too complex to describe here, but a starting point is "boolean algebra".

Now the shapes (letters, characters) "0" and "1" are labels we apply to those concepts. As such, you are absolutely correct that they are an alphabet, just a very small one, with only two symbols.

I think your question is why the computer doesn't accept a larger alphabet than two (binary).

One reason is that, given "boolean algebra", it doesn't have to.

But another is that distinguishing between presence and absence of voltage is easy, and doesn't have to be precise (you can decide, for example, that less than 0.8V means "0" (as was true for TTL logig from the 1970s on).

But distinguishing between 10 different voltages for an alphabet of "0" to "9" or worse, 26 different voltages for "A" to "Z" is a much harder problem, and would be much less reliable.

So binary logic is the almost inevitable design choice.

Comment: Very nice answer.